# mysql process cannot be stopped

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, percona

I have recently installed 5.5.28-29.2 Percona Server (GPL), Release 29.2 in a Ubuntu 12.04 OS Desktop. I have tried to stop the server using different methods:

```
- sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
- sudo kill -9 pid
- mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

All this methods stop the process, however it starts up automatically after it dies. I have checked syslog (/var/log/syslog/) and always shows me the next trace:

```
Jan  4 17:50:44 kernel: [ 1915.494219] init: mysql main process (17311) killed by KILL signal
Jan  4 17:50:44 kernel: [ 1915.494245] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Jan  4 17:50:44 kernel: [ 1915.500025] type=1400 audit(1357318244.557:48): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=18458 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan  4 17:50:46 /etc/mysql/debian-start[18501]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Jan  4 17:50:46 /etc/mysql/debian-start[18504]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Jan  4 17:50:46 /etc/mysql/debian-start[18504]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Jan  4 17:50:46 /etc/mysql/debian-start[18504]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Jan  4 17:50:46 /etc/mysql/debian-start[18504]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.28, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Jan  4 17:50:46 /etc/mysql/debian-start[18515]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Jan  4 17:50:46 /etc/mysql/debian-start[18520]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
```

Do you know the reason why the process restarts automatically ?
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I was having this exact same problem. Running the `kill` command would kill the process, but in my case it would keep popping up again under a different process ID.

The only way I could figure out how to stop it for good was this:

```
sudo stop mysql
```

Source: http://www.itfromscratch.com/how-to-stop-the-percona-mysql-server/

Comment: What about `sudo stop mysqld`?

Comment: Output: `stop: Unknown job: mysqld`

Comment: What about `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`?

Comment: I was also having the exact same problem and your solution did the trick
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: @The New Guy I tried  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop` instead. Didn't work.

Comment: What about `sudo service mysql stop`?

Answer (score 32):

Using `sudo service mysql stop` worked for me.

Comment: The main issue is the service flag in ubuntu, `kill -9`  or `stop` would do the trick with any other distro.
You have to look into the mysql log. It must say at the bottom: `/[path]/mysqld: Shutdown complete`, otherwise your daemon is up. You can check it live through: `tail -f /[path]/name.log`.

Great answer.

Answer (score 18):

Want to kill all mysql instances?  Try as root:

```
 pkill mysqld;
```

Comment: I have also tried to kill all instances with pkill but it still starts up. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Homebrew on Mac OS. `brew services stop mysql` did *not* work for me, but `sudo brew services stop mysql` did.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess here, but mysqld might be started via the mysql_safe init script, which will restart the server.

Comment: You are right, mysqld is being started via mysql_safe init script. However I think that if I use /etc/init.d/mysql stop the server shouldn't restart automatically. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For those looking at this years after the fact, I had a similar issue and just solved it.

Seems there was a second init script called orig_mysql.conf that existed in the /etc/init directory along with the mysql.conf file.  This caused upstart to start two instances and apparently it got confused when one was ended.  As such a continuous respawning took place.

My solution:

1. Stop mysql via upstart if possible:   `service mysql stop`
2. REMOVE one of the conf files (I removed /etc/init/orig_mysql.conf).  Then restart init using:  `telinit u`
3. Kill off any remaining mysqld processes manually.

Once you confirm you have no mysqld processes running and that they are not respawning any longer, restart mysql with `service mysql start`.

Hope this helps someone.  It took me two years to solve this.

Comment: Thanks ! It helped.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to this particular problem but here it goes anyways. I checked the error log ("/var/log/mysql/error.log") and saw that "explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=TRUE" was causing an error ("Unknown variable"). So I removed it from my.cnf ("/etc/mysql/my.cnf"), and ran "sudo start mysql" and it was back up and running. I hope this helps as well!