# unable to kill mysqld process

Tags: mysql, macos

Im trying to kill mysqld process but some how it respawn with different process id.(I'm on mac)

ps ax | grep mysql

```
 979   ??  Ss     0:00.31 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
```

sudo kill -9 979

```
1181   ??  Ss     0:00.31 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161415/mysql-process-cannot-be-stopped)

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091414/how-to-stop-mysqld